# jsbin does not recognize document ready in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsbin

See: http://jsbin.com/ebudec/edit#javascript,html

---

It seems strange but I think jsBin doesn't recognize the jQuery document ready (other syntax - which I use a lot) in **IE** :

```
$(function () {});
```

[jQuery.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) says :

> The .ready() method is typically used with an anonymous function:
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>   // Handler for .ready() called.
> });
> ```
>
> Which is equivalent to calling:
>
> ```
> $(function() {
>  // Handler for .ready() called.
> });
> ```

Comment: But how is this a problem with JSBin? jQuery is jQuery. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FelixKling did you see its not working ?

Comment: I have had multiple issues like that, I've since switched to http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following test code to your jsbin:

```
$(document).ready(function () {alert('');}); // Works!
$(function () {alert('');}); // Fails
```

The second line most definitely throws an error in IE. The interesting thing is that the IE debugger showed the following markup:

```
<script>
window.onload = (function () {alert('');});
$(function () {alert('');});
</script>
```

The debugger also did not have the `$` or `jQuery` objects defined. It looks like jsbin was somehow trying to parse out the jQuery code???

Comment: if he wont fix it he will loose users....not because of this syntax but that his site is not professional enough to deal with jquery at his whole

Comment: @Royi - Maybe he will fix it; I entered a ticket for the problem here: https://github.com/remy/jsbin/issues/125